# How do I control the size and position of chapter headings made from the titlesec package

Tags: spacing, chapters, fontsize, titlesec, books

> Set up

The code for my chosen "new chapter" page style is given below

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
%********************************CHAPTER SETTINGS*********************
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color} %remove blindtext after 
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75} %1=white, 0=black
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}} %spacing between line and text
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries} %spacing across entire page

%----------------------------------BEGIN------------------------------
\begin{document}

\chapter{Less is More}
\blindtext

\chapter*{more is less}
\blindtext

%----------------------------------END------------------------------
\end{document}
```

> Question

What can I add to control the position of the heading on the page (i.e. amount of white space from the top of the page to "less is more"). And how do I control the size of the text and number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `format` part, ie the first `{\Huge\bfseries}` as a hook for the pre-code and inserted some `\vspace*`. Please tweak it as you wish and consider whether the solution is acceptable

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
%********************************CHAPTER SETTINGS*********************
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color} %remove blindtext after 
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75} %1=white, 0=black
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}} %spacing between line and text
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\vspace*{4em}\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{} %spacing across entire page

%----------------------------------BEGIN------------------------------
\begin{document}

\chapter{Less is More}
\blindtext

\chapter*{more is less}
\blindtext

%----------------------------------END------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see how {\vspace*{4em} is controlling the position and I thankyou. what units is "em" I've seen it around a lot lately with "custom code". How would you adjust the size of text and number in the same way?

Comment: @UniStuffz em is a relative unit of measure and depends upon the selected font size. Usually it's similar to the font size itself. For the other questions, I thin you either should read the documentation of the titlesec package, or post a different question, in order to keep the standard of 1 post per question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `\titlespacing*`(the starred version deletes the first paragraph indent) and a scaled chapter number. Note that `\Huge\bfseries`  in the first argument is valid for the whole title and doesn't have to be repeated in the last argument:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
%********************************CHAPTER SETTINGS*********************
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color} %remove blindtext after
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75} %1=white, 0=black
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}} %spacing between line and text
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\scalebox{2}{\thechapter}\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{3pt}{} %spacing across entire page
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{80pt}

%----------------------------------BEGIN------------------------------
\begin{document}

\chapter{Less is More}
\blindtext

\chapter*{more is less}
\blindtext

%----------------------------------END------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can play around with, the code you put adjusts the number but how do you adjust the text?

Comment: and which part of the code is removing the indentation.

Comment: Removing the indentation is obtained with `\titlespacing*`. Using `\titlespacing` Maintains it. By `text adjusting`, what do you mean? Position or size?

Comment: as in increase the size of the text "less is more" to match the size of the number which is increased by \scalebox